# unix command for filtering matching data in 2files

Tags: shell, unix

Below is the case:

File1.csv

```
1,2  
3,4  
5,6  
7,8
```

File 2.csv

```
2  
4  
8
```

Then I want to read File2.csv and compare it with second coloumn of file1.csv and if matched then take the complete row of file1 and put it in file3.

File3

```
1,2  
3,4  
7,8
```

I am lloking for unix command to do so?

Comment: where is line 1,2 comming from in File3 ?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR { a[$1]=$1 ; } NR>FNR { if ( $2 in a ) print ;}' File2.csv File1.csv
```

where

- `FNR==NR { a[$1]=$1 ; }` select first file (File2.csv), and remember value in array a
- `NR>FNR { if ( $2 in a ) print ;}` for next file, if second column in array, print.

Answer (score 0):

A (readable) perl version is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my %lookup;
open FILE, "File1.csv" or die "Couldn't open file: $!";
while (<FILE>){
    chomp;
    my ($left, $right) = split(',', $_);

    $lookup{$right} = $_;
}
close FILE;

open FILE, "File2.csv" or die "Couldn't open file: $!";
open OUT_FILE, ">File3.csv" or die "Couldn't open file: $!";
while (<FILE>){
    chomp;

    if (exists ($lookup{$_})) {
      print OUT_FILE "$lookup{$id}\n";
    }
}
close FILE;
close OUT_FILE;
```

Store the code e.g. as  so_33254185.pl and call

```
$>perl so_33254185.pl
```

I know you asked for pure shell solution, but maybe this allows you to improve it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {seen[$1]; next} $2 in seen' file2.csv file1.csv > file3.csv
cat file3.csv
1,2
3,4
7,8
```